# How many combinations of two sets?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

This question may have been answered, but not being a mathematician at all I don't know how to search or even to explain it properly.

Suppose I have a grid of 4 rows and 2 columns. The right column contains 4 blue balls (b), and I have 2 red balls (r) that I need to put into the left column, trying each combination. Like so (* = no ball):

One red ball gives 4 combinations:

1. rb, *b, *b, *b
2. *b, rb, *b, *b
3. *b, *b, rb, *b
4. *b, *b, *b, rb

Two red balls gives 6 combinations:

1. rb, rb, *b, *b
2. rb, *b, rb, *b
3. rb, *b, *b, rb
4. *b, rb, rb, *b
5. *b, rb, *b, rb
6. *b, *b, rb, rb

etc.

I can figure it out by hand if I know the number of red and blue balls, but I was wondering if there is a way to put this as a formula, in which I can just plug in the number of red balls and the number of blue balls (i.e., rows) and which then outputs the number of combinations.

Comment: The number of combinations is called "binomial coefficient", and it's denoted by the symbol $\binom{n}{k}$, where $n$ is the number of rows and $k$ is the number of red balls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of such combinations is called "binomial coefficient", and it's denoted by the symbol $\binom{n}{k}$, where $n$ is the number of blue balls and $k$ is the number of red balls. The formula is $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2) \cdots (n-k+1)}{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots (k-1) \cdot k}$$

For example, for $n=4$ and $k=2$ you have
$$\binom{4}{2} = \frac{4 \cdot 3}{1 \cdot 2} = 6$$